# Need help to understand different formula for Trapezoidal's rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

My book (Numerical Analysis by Douglas) said the formula for Trapezoidal's rule is

$$\int_a^b f(x)\, \Bbb dx \approx \frac h2 \left(f(a) + f(b) + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(x_k)\right)$$

Here is the screenshot from the book. (i exclude the error)

[image]

And also from wolfram documentation i found the different formula like this:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\, \Bbb dx \approx \frac h2 \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (f(hk)+ f(h(1+k)))\right)$$

Here is the screenshot of the formula on my android app "Wolfram Calculus" when i was evaluating the $\sin(x)$:

[image]

I've tested those formula for finding the integral of $\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and got the same result, the same absolute error, and the same relative error. Which means there's a possibility those formulas are supposed to be equivalent.

So, i realize there is a property like this:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} i = \sum_{k=1}^{n} i-1$$
But the upper bound on the wolfram documentation doesn't change. I'm really confuse now. Can you explain why those are equivalent? I don't get why $f(a)+f(b)$ dissapeared and $f(x_k)$ is replaced by $(f(hk)+ f(h(1+k)))$. And the constant 2 is missing too.

I included the algebra precalculus as a tag because my question is more about algebraic manipulation rather than numerical analysis.

Hope you can explain it to me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you write out the first couple of terms and the last couple of terms.

The formula you got from "Wolfram documentation" has an error, in that it assumes that $a = 0$.  The correct formula is a bit messier:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx ≈ \frac{h}{2}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\big(f(a + hk) +f(a + h(k+1))\big)$$
Now if you put in $k=0$, the first term becomes $$\frac{h}{2}\cdot\big(f(a) + f(a + h)\big)$$ and the second term becomes $$\frac{h}{2}\cdot\big(f(a + h) + f(a + 2h)\big)$$ while the last two terms become
$$\frac{h}{2}\cdot\big(f(a + (n-2)h) + f(a + (n-1)h)\big)$$ and $$\frac{h}{2}\cdot\big(f(a + (n-1)h) + f(a + nh)\big)$$ so the last term in the last part is $f(b)$ because $a + nh = b$.
So you can see that the $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ terms show up once, and all the terms in the middle show up twice.

Comment: Did you forget $h$ on the first term of the last expression sir? Shouldn't it be $f(a+(n-1)h)$. Overall thank you so much for explaining.

Comment: Good catch! Edited to fix.